# How to draw and label vertices of a polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, paths, coordinates, line

I am drawing a convex polygon and a line connecting two points *on* edges.
However, as shown in the figure below, the endpoints of the line are not on the edges. How to fix that?

[image: convex-polygon-line]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw] (0,0) node[left] (6) {6}
    -- (1.5,-1) node[below] (5) {5}
    -- (3.5, -0.8) node[below] (4) {4}
    -- (5,0) node[right] (3) {3}
    -- (4, 1.5) node[above] (2) {2}
    -- (1,2) node[above] (1) {1}
    -- cycle;

    \draw ($(3)!0.4!(4)$) -- ($(1)!0.4!(2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because your `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, etc. nodes are the labels, not the points.

Here a possible solution using `\coordinate`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (1) at (1,2); 
    \coordinate (2) at (4, 1.5); 
    \coordinate (3) at (5,0); 
    \coordinate (4) at (3.5, -0.8); 
    \path[draw] (0,0) node[left] {6}
    -- (1.5,-1) node[below] {5}
    -- (4) node[below] {4}
    -- (3) node[right] {3}
    -- (2) node[above] {2}
    -- (1) node[above] {1}
    -- cycle;

    \draw ($(3)!0.4!(4)$) -- ($(1)!0.4!(2)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can see the explanation why it is not working in the [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424126/9335).
To overcome this you can replace `node[position] (n) {n}` by `coordinate[label=position:n] (n)`. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw] (0,0) coordinate[label=left:6] (6)
      -- (1.5,-1) coordinate[label=below:5] (5)
      -- (3.5, -0.8) coordinate[label=below:4] (4)
      -- (5,0) coordinate[label=right:3] (3)
      -- (4, 1.5) coordinate[label=above:2] (2)
      -- (1,2) coordinate[label=above:1] (1)
      -- cycle;

    \draw[red] ($(3)!0.4!(4)$) -- ($(1)!0.4!(2)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The lines `(3) -- (4)` and `(1) -- (2)` connect the nodes, the center point of the nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw] (0,0) node[left] (6) {6}
    -- (1.5,-1) node[below] (5) {5}
    -- (3.5, -0.8) node[below] (4) {4}
    -- (5,0) node[right] (3) {3}
    -- (4, 1.5) node[above] (2) {2}
    -- (1,2) node[above] (1) {1}
    -- cycle;

    \draw[red] (3) -- (4) (1) -- (2);
    \draw[blue] ($(3)!0.4!(4)$) -- ($(1)!0.4!(2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Visualization of the connection lines to illustrate the problem]

Instead of the center points of the nodes, you need their anchor points:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw] (0,0) node[left] (6) {6}
    -- (1.5,-1) node[below] (5) {5}
    -- (3.5, -0.8) node[below] (4) {4}
    -- (5,0) node[right] (3) {3}
    -- (4, 1.5) node[above] (2) {2}
    -- (1,2) node[above] (1) {1}
    -- cycle;

    \draw[red] ($(3.west)!0.4!(4.north)$) -- ($(1.south)!0.4!(2.south)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result using anchor points]

However, this is a maintenance nightmare. If a label is moved, it requires a fix of the anchor point as well. Therefore, it is cleaner to define the polygon vertices as coordinates as shown in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424124/16967) of CarLaTeX.